# Hiding API Key with config-vars on React app deployed on heroku, trying to access the keys but not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I have created a react-app that makes an API call and displays the results on the page, that's it.

After adding my API Key through Heroku's config vars, I put in this for key "api_key" and then I added my key in the value section.

I put in the following code at the top of the

```
let api_key = process.env.bitquery_key
```

Now, in the section of the javasript code that calls the API Key I put this:
`X-API-KEY": api_key`

This doesn't work. The API Key is invalid.

I also tried to do

```
console.log(api_key)
```

This didn't work either. Would apperciate some help, I tried to look around but no one made videos on this and couldn't find on stackoverflow, guess its super easy so no one had an issue with it lol. Appreciate the help, thanks